# WordPress plugin combination

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the pie registration plugin and I want to know how can I automatically define a role (in my case I want to define as subscriber) when people register and login. I want to do this because I want to restrict some zones of the website and redirect those zones for the register or login page. Since the free version of the plugin doesn't have restricted areas, I'm also using the plugin called members that does 50% of what I want. So I want to combine these 2 plugins' functionalities.

tldr: how can I give the role subscriber on pie-registration?

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to register user you have assign it a role for ex.
if you are using wp_insert_user( $userdata ) function than you can assign user role in $userdata as follows.

```
$userdata = array(
'user_login'  =>  'login_name',
'user_pass'   =>  'pass',
'role'        =>  'role'   // When creating an user, `user_pass` is expected.
```

);

There are some default roles in wordpress , you can also creates new roles by using following code.

```
<?php add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities ); ?>
```

And you can assign capabilities, so by using this two function you can achieve your goal. 
You can read more about:[wp_insert_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) , [add_role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)